Nest js websockets Subscribe message isnt working
I have a users service class:
// users.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma.service';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

    async findOne(username: string) {

        console.log("username in service: ", username);

        return this.prisma.users.findUnique({
            where: { username },
        });
    }

    async createUser(data: { username: string; password: string; role: string }) {
        return this.prisma.users.create({
            data,
        });
    }

    async findFirstCoordinator() {
        return this.prisma.users.findFirst({
            where: { username: 'COORDINATOR' },
        });
    }
}

And the main websocket class:
import { WebSocketGateway, SubscribeMessage, MessageBody, ConnectedSocket, WebSocketServer, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';
import { UsersService } from 'src/Services/users.service';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma.service';

@WebSocketGateway({
    namespace: '/chat',
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
      methods: ['GET', 'POST']
    }
  })
  export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  
    constructor(private usersService: UsersService, private prisma: PrismaService) {}
  
    async handleConnection(client: Socket) {
      console.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
    }
  
    async handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
      console.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
    }
  
    @SubscribeMessage('register')
    async handleRegister(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket, @MessageBody() data: { username: string }) {
      console.log("username: ", data.username);
      const user = await this.usersService.findOne(data.username);
      if (!user) {
        client.emit('error', 'User not found');
        return;
      }
      client.data.user = user; // Store user details in socket data
      client.join(user.id.toString()); // Join a room named after the user's ID
    }
  
    @SubscribeMessage('message')
    async handleMessage(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket, @MessageBody() data: { targetId?: number; message: string }) {
      const user = client.data.user;
      if (!user) {
        client.emit('error', 'User not registered');
        return;
      }
  
      const coordinator = await this.usersService.findFirstCoordinator();
      const targetId = coordinator.id;

  
      const message = await this.prisma.message.create({
        data: {
          userId: user.id,
          targetId: targetId,
          text: data.message,
        }
      });
  
      this.server.to(targetId.toString()).emit('receiveMessage', {
        from: user.username,
        message: data.message,
        messageId: message.id,
        createdAt: message.createdAt
      });
    }
  }

So, when i start the project and in postman make socket.io request to ws://localhost:3001/chat and press Connect, it connects and in server message that client is connected is printed, but when i try to "register" or send "message" server does not respond at all
